# Regular Expression in C# to extract data from a string

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

```
var searchIn = "The quick brown fox jump over the 3 lazy dogs";
```

I want to get 3 from this string only if they are followed by "lazy dogs"
or 13 if the number is 13

the only way i found was to do this...

```
var x = Regex.Match(Regex.Match(searchIn, @"\d{1,2} lazy dogs").Value, @"\d{1,2}");
```

is there a better way?

Comment: How about positive lookahead, something like `\d++(?= lazy dogs)`.

Comment: Another option, other than the way more elegant positive lookahead, is to use groups: Regex.Match(searchIn, @"(\d{1,2}) lazy dogs").Groups[0].Value

Comment: Both worked RegEx is amazing...